# How to make global post work with custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, globals

I was wondering to know if it's possible to use global posts with custom_types. I was working with this function:

```
global $post; 
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=4&offset=1& category=3,4'); 
foreach($myposts as $post) : 
    setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Visualizza <?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/posthumb/<?php $values = get_post_custom_values("Image"); echo $values[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" /></a>
<?php endforeach;
```

As soon as I've moved the post from the standard articles type to a new custom post type, this stopped working. The category is still the same. Can I get it work again in any kind of way?

Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `get_posts()` uses a default post type of `post`.

If you want to select from a CPT then you need this:

```
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=4&offset=1&category=3,4&post_type=YOUr_CPT_HERE');
```

Comment: Thanks Brady! I was going crazy trying to find that option!!! Thank you so much!!!